# Judaism and 'Hospice Limited' Care

Tags: pikuachnefesh-danger-life, noachide-laws

Let me preface this by saying that I am sure there are many cases in which hospice is likely the best/only place for a person nearing the end of their life-- the only place where their intense medical needs can be met and at least some comfort given. That being said, the concept of 'residential' hospice is a bit different, in that they provide food, (some) medication, and other necessities of life but do not provide any mental or physical stimulation, socialization, or any effort to improve the patient's health. They often cease 'maintenance' medications (e.g, those for type 2 diabetes).

The question then becomes, how is this type of 'hospice' viewed in the context of Judaism? Obviously, life is a gift from G-d and not to be dealt with anything other than the highest respect and consideration. ("Whoever destroys one life is as if he destroyed a whole world, and whoever preserves a life is as if he preserved the whole world." -Sanhedrin 4:5) No one in this situation is actively doing anything to destroy a life. But they're not making a *positive*  effort to preserve it, either.

I have encountered a lot of people saying "its about comfort" while, in the same breath stating that by not providing activities, stimulation, etc, the person will lapse into a more vegetative state and/or get depressed, stop eating, and die. I'm having a lot of trouble with this because it seems like seeing someone bleeding to death of a cut and just stepping over them (or holding their hand, if you want to buy the comfort spiel) rather than trying to stem the flow of blood. Moreover, I was fortunate enough to find a very nice pamphlet called "A Jewish Response to Dementia" by Rabbi Cary Kozberg, in which he emphasized that its important to allow that person to participate in whatever way they are able, for as long as they are able.

In situations like this, how can one honor the elderly patient, continue to respect them as a spiritual being, as well as abide by halacha and the ultimate directive G-d expresses by giving us life in the first place?

Comment: A very good question. A very broad topic. I am very curious, can you give a link for the "A Jewish rep. to dementia"?

Comment: Paragraph 3 reminded me of Vayikra (Leviticus) 19:16.

Comment: @kouty- Thank you. Unfortunately, I don't have a link to the text itself-- it was kindly provided to me by a Jewish nursing home in my area. The subtitle of the article was "Honoring Broken Tablets", and the author compares dementia patients to the original set of tablets from Sinai-- broken, but still holy. It's really one of the best analogies I've found. The publisher's website is http://www.jewishlights.com.

Comment: @ephraimhelfgot- That's a really interesting point, especially given how expensive even the 'basic' level of residential hospice (room, board, OTC pain meds) can be when compared to a regular nursing home.